# How do hackers use C&C servers without revealing their identity and keep them up?

Tags: malware, anonymity

I recently watched a couple of YouTube videos about malware analysis and in most of the cases, the reverse engineer easily found out which IP address the malware connects to.

Usually, there is a link between the IP address and the identity of a person. If one does something illegal (like downloading copyrighted movies), the police can find out your identity by asking your ISP to whom this IP address belongs.

So my question is: How do hackers rent a public server without revealing their identity? And why don't those servers get taken down quickly by the company that hosts the servers? Even if they hide their identity while renting the server, the hosting company should take the server down as soon as they get knowledge about the fact that the server is used for illegal activities, right? So how do they manage to keep their control servers up for years and also hide their identity? And why can't the police/Interpol or whoever do anything against it?

Comment: "Usually, there is a link between the IP address" -- only when a lot of other data is used. Not on its own. "How do hackers rent a public server without revealing their identity?" -- why do you think they are rented?

Comment: _How do hackers rent a public server without revealing their identity?_ Stolen credit card numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't get into the law enforcement side of things because of my lack of knowledge, but your second sentence is not necessarily correct.

> Usually there is a link between the IP adress[sic] and the identity of a person.

Without going into a long explanation about how ISP providers work (which is definitely worth looking into) I can simply say that criminals don't typically rent servers ;).

The IP address acting as a Command and Control (C2) server is often a compromised (hacked) computer owned by someone else. That's what botnets are all about.

There is also the use of VPNs (virtual private networks) and TOR which can hide the origin of the connection request. A great deal of "hacking" info about this can be found in [this US CISA alert](https://us-cert.cisa.gov/ncas/alerts/aa20-183a).

Using TOR makes it "difficult for network defenders and authorities to perform system recovery and respond to cyberattacks"[1](https://us-cert.cisa.gov/ncas/alerts/aa20-183a).

For example, there is an IOS app called TunnelBear. I can turn on TunnelBear from my home in Canada, and set my outgoing IP address to come from Cypress or some other country. This allows a continuous connection between my device and the remote server in both directions as long as I stay connected. [ed. TunnelBear is likely [a bad example](https://privacycanada.net/tunnelbear-vpn-review/), but I chose it because I have experience with it and iOS devices are very common.-R-]

People who typically download pirated movies or software are usually not full-fledged malicious hackers, and don't typically use any of the techniques described above, which is why the Police can track them through their ISP.

Comment: Kevin Mitnick's book "The Art of Invisibility" gives plenty of examples on how an ordinary person can stay private online, use burner phones, and generally maintain anonymity.